# Restrict contact creation for non-English language embedded service chat using extra JS snippet setting file

Tags: pre-chat, embedded-services

I've got a multilingual community and added standard embedded service chat component in the footer and overridden features using an external snippet setting file named Prechat JS.

I've already added code in **embedded_svc.snippetSettingsFile.extraPrechatInfo** for not to create contact and only create/search a Person Account.
It works for the English language but if I change the language e.g (Spanish) then it does create a contact instead of Person account.

Comment: Hello!  Were you able to resolve this issue? I am encountering the same issue

Comment: Not actually, we contacted Salesforce for this issue, however, they could not help...

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the find or create uses the label and not the API name. You need to provide the translated label in your mapping. Here's an example for contacts with Spanish chats.

```
{
                "entityFieldMaps": [{
                    "doCreate": false,
                    "doFind": true,
                    "fieldName": "LastName",
                    "isExactMatch": true,
                    "label": "Nombre
                }, {
                    "doCreate": false,
                    "doFind": true,
                    "fieldName": "FirstName",
                    "isExactMatch": true,
                    "label": "Apellidos"
                }, {
                    "doCreate": false,
                    "doFind": true,
                    "fieldName": "Email",
                    "isExactMatch": true,
                    "label": "Correo electrónico"
                }],
                "entityName": "Contact"
            }
```